# How to Implement Plaid with c#

Tags: c#, plaid

I'm using Ackara/Plaid.NET (https://github.com/Ackara/Plaid.NET) but for lack of documentation, I'm stuck on how to get the Routing # and Account #.

Have anyone implemented Plaid with .Net willing to share?

Tried to use the code below but didn't work

```
  var request  = await client.FetchAccountInfoAsync(new Acklann.Plaid.Auth.GetAccountInfoRequest()
        {
            AccessToken = accessToken.AccessToken,
            ClientId = "<clientid>",
            Secret = "<secret>",
            Options = new Acklann.Plaid.Auth.GetAccountInfoOptions
            {
                AccountIds = bankId
            }
        });
```

Sorry I should have been more specific when I said it didn't work. This is the error message I got but I'm lost on how to make it work.
Error Message:  [image]

Comment: Please post your error as text, not as an image. That makes it easier to index, saves bandwidth, and some people have image hosting sites blocked.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string as an AccountId. AccountID is an array of strings. I changed the following line and it worked for me.

```html
AccountIds = new string[] { "xxxxxxxxxxx" }
```